# How to force docker compose recreate manually deleted volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The `docker-compose.yml` contains a volume definition and a service that uses it.

```
#(This is a reduced but representative example)
services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo:3.6.11
        ...
        volumes:
          - "mongodb:/data/db/"

volumes:
    mongodb:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
          type: "none"
          o: "bind"
          device: "$PWD/.storage/mongodb"
```

I've removed the entire `.storage/mongodb` directory, wanting to force the next `docker-compose up` not reuse any volume.

Instead, I received an error: docker was missing its volume data.

```
Creating mongo       ... error

ERROR: for mongo  Cannot create container for service mongo: failed to mount local volume: mount <...>/.storage/mongodb:/var/lib/docker/volumes/mongodb/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
```

How I tried to resolve that:

1. `docker-build up --build --force-recreate`. Container's build and restart don't work.
2. `docker volume ls -q | while read id;  do docker volume rm "$id"; done`. Removing volumes didn't seem to help either.

I assume that docker is able to recover from the removed volumes data, since the very first `docker-compose up` runs without initialised `.storage` directory.

Basically, I want `docker-compose up` to work.

It also would be fantastic to understand the issue.

Look forward to your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried docker-compose up with -V option?

```
-V, --renew-anon-volumes   Recreate anonymous volumes instead of retrieving
                               data from the previous containers.
```

Comment: Tried this option, still getting the error:
`Cannot start service <...> error while mounting volume  <...> failed to mount local volume: mount <...> flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I solved it by shutting down Docker Destop and re-run it.